# How to insert values in dynamically nested hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of strings of unknown length (but let's say up to 5). I have also an empty hash `h = {}` and a value.

I want to transform the array and the value to hash like this:

```
val = 1
h = {}
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
# result I want:
{
  'a' => {
    'b' => {
      'c' => {
        'd' => 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What's important is that some of the keys might already exist (created in a loop iteration before). So I might have:

```
val = 2
h = {'a' => {'b' => {'c' => {'d' => 1}}}}
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']
# result I want:
{
  'a' => {
    'b' => {
      'c' => {
        'd' => 1,
        'e' => 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again, [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to the rescue:

```
def dredge(hash, list, value = nil)
  # Snip off the last element
  *list, tail = list

  # Iterate through the elements in the path...
  final = list.inject(hash) do |h, k|
    # ...and populate with a hash if necessary.
    h[k] ||= { }
  end

  # Add on the final value
  final[tail] = value

  hash
end
```

This could be improved a little depending on how resilient you need it to be on things like zero-length lists and so on.

Here it is applied:

```
h = {}
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
dredge(h, a, 1)
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>1}}}}

h = {'a' => {'b' => {'c' => {'d' => 1}}}}
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']

dredge(h, a, 2)
# => {"a"=>{"b"=>{"c"=>{"d"=>1, "e"=>2}}}}
```

Comment: I was about to post the same :-) You could use `*list, tail = list` to avoid mutating `list`

Comment: True, that's probably a better idea. Let me change that.